# Модулярная арифметика

Tags: математика, арифметика

Как реализовать модулярные операции?
Допустим, те же умножение, сложение, возведение в степень?

Чтобы при **1/4 (mod11)** было **3**, да и как оно вообще выходит так? 
Достаточно будет и формулы.

Upd.

Сложение, вычитание, умножение работают так же, как и в обычной арифметике, разница лишь в том, что от результата берется mod n.

Их можно упростить по принципу:

**(a # b) mod n = [a mod n # b mod n] mod n**, где # — любое действие из -,+,*

А возведение в степень — это либо mod стандартного pow, либо с поэтапным умножением и сокращением множителей.

А по поводу деления написано ниже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Малая теорема ферма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)
Из неё [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Отсюда

> a / b = a * b  <sup>p-2</sup>  (mod p)

```
1/4 = 1 * (4 ^ 9) = 4 ^ 9 mod 11 = 3
```